# More than one asp:Repeater Control using same datasource

Tags: asp.net

In my project I am having my profile form.The form having profile,physical,other and about user information.I have created tabs for all this i.e for profile,physical,other,about user information.I am having different div tag which are having repeater control, which contain information regarding related tabs.I am having member Profile table in database which contains all this information.So I have created data set which hold all this information from table,and I am using that single data set to bind data to repeater controls.Problem is when I clicked on tabs only first tab shows information but when I clicked on another tabs they open the div but not showing information.I am giving my code please check it out,and give any solution on how to use repeater control more than one on a single form,and can use same data set for binding data.I also want to ask can use form view control for this purpose.`enter code here`
     
                    
                        
                            
                        
                        
                            
                                
                                    Height:
                                
                                
                                    <%#Eval("height")%>
                                
                            
                            
                                
                                    Weight"
                                
                                
                                    <%#Eval("wt") %>
                                
                            
                            
                                
                                    Skin Color:
                                
                                
                                    <%#Eval("skincolor")%>
                                
                            
                            
                                
                                    Eye Sight:
                                
                                
                                    <%#Eval("eyesight")%>

```
            </div>
            <div id="aboutMe" runat="server" visible="false" style="margin-left: 50px;     display: none">
                <asp:Repeater ID="repAbootMe" runat="server">
                    <HeaderTemplate>
                        <table>
                    </HeaderTemplate>
                    <ItemTemplate>
                        <tr>
                            <td class="directorytdWidth">
                                About Me:
                            </td>
                            <td class="directoryTdPadding">
                                <%#Eval("aboutMe")%>
                            </td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                                <td class="directorytdWidth">
                                Active Friendship Zone:
                                </td>
                                <td class="directoryTdPadding">
                                <%#Eval("friendship")%>
                                </td>
                        </tr>

                </ItemTemplate>
                <FooterTemplate>
                    </table></FooterTemplate>
```

I have bind the data in code behind,because I have created stored procedure for this.
Please suggest me any solution.Thanks in advance

code behind:`enter code here`
     protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            Int32 candiid = (Int32)(Session["candiID"]);
            InsertRegistation viewProfile = new InsertRegistation();
            DataSet ds = viewProfile.ViewProfile(candiid);
            repProfileInfo.DataSource = ds;
           repProfileInfo.DataBind();
           repPhysicalInfo.DataSource = ds;
           repPhysicalInfo.DataBind();
           repAbootMe.DataSource = ds;
           repAbootMe.DataBind();
           repOtherInfo.DataSource = ds;
           repOtherInfo.DataBind();

```
        string id = Request.QueryString["id"];
        if (!IsPostBack)
        {
            if (id == null)
             {
                if (profileInfo.Visible == false)
                {
                    repProfileInfo.DataSource = ds;
                    repProfileInfo.DataBind();
                    profileInfo.Visible = true;
                }
            }
            switch (id)
            {
                 case "profileInfo": if (profileInfo.Visible == false)
                    {
                        repProfileInfo.DataSource = ds;
                        repProfileInfo.DataBind();
                        profileInfo.Visible = true;
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        profileInfo.Visible = false;
                    }
                    break;
                case "physicalInfo": if (physicalInfo.Visible == false)
                    {
                        repPhysicalInfo.DataSource = ds;
                        repPhysicalInfo.DataBind();
                        physicalInfo.Visible = true;
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        physicalInfo.Visible = false;
                    }
                    break;
                case "aboutMe": if (aboutMe.Visible == false)
                    {
                        repAbootMe.DataSource = ds;
                        repAbootMe.DataBind();
                        aboutMe.Visible = true;
                    }  
                    else
                    {
                        aboutMe.Visible = false;
                    }
                    break;
                case "otherInfo": if (otherInfo.Visible == false)
                    {
                        repOtherInfo.DataSource = ds;
                        repOtherInfo.DataBind();
                        otherInfo.Visible = true;
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        otherInfo.Visible = false;
                     }
                     break;

            }

         }

     }
```

Comment: When you right click > View page source on the html side, does the data appear in place? It might be a tab control problem not a repeater issue

Comment: I think there is a problem with tab. Where you are binding all this tab?

Comment: I am binding tabs in code behind.

Comment: I have given the code behind please check it and suggest me solution